# Best way to check duplicate record when insert DB record thorugh spring data jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Our user can create customer record in different places. After he / she search for customer by ID no. and no customer record is found in the database, he / she will enter the customer detail to create the customer record. However, it is expect that he / she should not able to save his / her customer record if another ID No exist in the database. As thousands of user may create customer in the same time, it is expected that our system should able to report the duplicate record error to our user.

By using spring data, we use the following code to save the customer information.

```
customerRepository.save(customer);
```

May I know any good way to detect the duplicate record error when insert data to database?
We may have met similar problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959523/force-insert-with-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: Ummm... Can't you set the column as unique in your DB..? Spring automatically throws a unique constraint violated exception. You can probably catch it and have your way with it.

Comment: Our experience is that spring data will update the record that have the same primary key instead of throw error.

Comment: Use surrogate primary key and add UNIQUE constraint on the property you want to have unique. This is something JPA will not handle for you. You will need to check that before the entity is persisted (before you call `save`).

Comment: Thanks Pavel's suggest. 
However, in our case, we cannot change the ID No as Primary Key which is used by different systems. We can add column(s) or add surrogate key(s), bu this cannot solve the update same ID No issue.

Comment: It seems that there is no standard way to handle this, I think we may use executeNativeSql to work around this problem.